# Comparing subspace topology C(R) with induced topology on C(R)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, function-spaces

I'm working on the second part of following problem (show C(R) finer than subspace topology):

Define $C(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ as the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Define the metric $\bar{d}: C(\mathbb{R}) \times C(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ by

$\bar{d}(f, g):=\min \{1, \sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)-g(x)|\}$

Show that $\bar{d}$ is a metric that induces a topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$ that is finer than the subspace topology.

So I know a basis element of topology induced by d is an epsilon ball around some function $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$. I don't really know how to compare this with the intersection of an open ball centered at $f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with $C(\mathbb{R})$. We can write a basis element of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ as $\prod_{\alpha}B_\alpha$ where $B_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$. Does it make sense to take $B_\beta \subseteq B_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ then say $\prod_{\beta}B_\beta \subseteq \prod_{\alpha}B_\alpha \cap C(R)$ for $\prod_{\beta}B_\beta \in C(R)$?

My concern is the existence of these $B_\beta$'s and what they represent (and I'm new to function spaces). I think $B_\beta$ would represent a neighborhood of $f(x_\beta)$ for $x_\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Sorry if this is unclear and any clarification/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wdym by open ball in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The topology induced by d is given by a basis of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ of the form $B_d(f, \epsilon)$ for $f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, $\epsilon > 0$ by definition.

Comment: No, $\overline{d}$ is defined as a metric on $C(\mathbb{R})$ so it defines topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Ah you're right! Let me edit the question directly to clarify this. I'm talking about the subspace topology there which is given by the intersection of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Also $\prod_{\beta}B_\beta \subseteq \prod_{\alpha}B_\alpha \cap C(R)$ is impossible unless each $B_\beta$ is a singleton or at least one is empty, so you likely don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets of the form $C(\mathbb{R})\cap \{g\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} : g(x_i)\in U_i, i = 1, 2, ..., n\}$ for $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $U_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ open, form a basis of $C(\mathbb{R})$ in the subspace topology. If $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ is an element of such set, by taking $0 < r_i < 1$ such that $(f(x_i)-r_i, f(x_i)+r_i)\subseteq U_i$, and then further taking $r = \min_{i=1, ..., n} r_i$, we can ensure that if $\overline{d}(f, g) < r$, then $g(x_i)\in U_i$ for $i = 1, ..., n$, that is $B(f, r)\subseteq C(\mathbb{R})\cap \{g\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} : g(x_i)\in U_i, i = 1, 2, ..., n\}$.

Comment: Does $r = \min_{i,..,n}r_i$ make sense because we may have uncountably many $r_i$? I guess just use $\inf$ maybe?

Comment: We have a finite number of $r_i$, each corresponding to $i\in \{1, ..., n\}$.

Comment: Oh I see because in product topology we have finitely many $U_i \neq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, we specify what set $g(x)$ belongs to only for finitely many $x$.